# MongoDB -- Query Performance through Java class

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am  new to the world of NoSQL databases and MongoDB.

I am trying to access the query execution time in Mongodb. I plan to do CURD operations with a set of 1000,10000 and 100000 records.I would also like to run few other random queries. I want to execute these queries through a java class. Can any one kindly suggest me the best way to get the response times from the java class file. I understand Database Profiler for mongodb is a good way, but would like to execute profiler commands through java.Could any one suggest how to execute Profiler commands from java  class for each query.

P.S: Kindly suggest if there is any better way. Any suggestion would be of a great help.

Comment: One way using which i improved my mongodb performance is by adding index to the collection. Sorry to not mention anything about java,however if you want to improve performance from mongodb end, indexing is a great way to kickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mongo Java client you would invoke `find()` in the usual way and then append a query modifier like so:

```
MongoCollection<...> collection = ...
FindIterable<...> results = collection.find(query).modifiers(new Document(QueryOperators.EXPLAIN, true));
```

This will return you Mongo's profiler document for that query.

Plenty of details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/) on the format, content etc of that document.

If you are interested in profiling you might also need to hint (i.e. force Mongo to use a specific index), this is done in much the same way, for example:

```
MongoCollection<...> collection = ...
FindIterable<...> results = collection.find().modifiers(new Document(QueryOperators.HINT, indexName));
```